# ignoring unconsumed columns while inserting into postgres database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to insert data into a table from a python dictionary. But my dictionary contains more keys than the columns in the table. So I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: column_name` while inserting. I want to just insert the column names that exist in the table and ignore extra columns.

How to do that using sqlalchemy?

The code I am using is

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

db = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://localhost:5432/postgres')
meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = db

data = [{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4,
    'e': 5,
    'f': 6
}]

ins_stmt = postgresql.insert(table_object).values(data)
db.execute(ins_stmt)
```

where my `table_object` contains columns a,b,c,d,e.

P.S.- I am using sqlalchemy 1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to get `insert` to discard the extra items, so they must be filtered out beforehand.  You could do this by comparing the table's column names against the dictionary's keys.

```py
column_names = table_object.columns.keys()
fixed = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in column_names} for d in data]

ins_stmt = postgresql.insert(table_object).values(fixed)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin():
        conn.execute(ins_stmt)
```

Comment: `for k, v in d.items() if k in (d.keys() & column_names)` `k` is always in d.keys(), no need to `&` here if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 Excellent point, I've removed the redundancy.